# Deploy Milvus on AKS with custom number of vector size

Tags: kubernetes, vector, apache-zookeeper, azure-aks, milvus

I am trying to deploy milvus on AKS cluster.
The helm chart (https://milvus.io/docs/install_cluster-helm.md#Install-Helm-Chart-for-Milvus) is working fine with the default values. But, I am increasing the vector size along with the others parameters too (this customization we can do here - https://milvus.io/tools/sizing/ ) and getting an helm-chart configuration YAML files for values, which we can use to install milvus cluster helm-chart deployment.

I have already provided much resources (nodes with proper CPU and memory), but still pods are in pending state.

[image]

Can anyone help me here!